# translateX css effect on hover

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I want to apply a `translateX` effect on some `<h4>` headings titles. I've tested the code and it's working, but I've noticed a little problem when the effect is executed. The problem is related to the position of the element on where is applied the translation, because I want that the effect is visible only when a parent div is hovered. The problem is that it will be showed also the nearest element also if it's not hovered.

Here is a sample of the code, I use bootstrap 4 card columns.

```html
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h4 class="title"><a href="#">link1</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h4 class="title"><a href="#">link2</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h4 class="title"><a href="#">link3</a></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<style>

.overlay{
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 1;
}

.card:hover .overlay{
opacity: 1;
}

.title{
transition: all 300ms;
transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.card:hover .title{
transition: all 300ms;
transform: translateX(0%);
}

</style>
```

Codepen demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOWyVK

Comment: Can you add it on a codepen please?

Comment: @Luca Spezzano Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `overflow:hidden;` inside the overlay class so it would be like that

```
.overlay{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Is that what you need?

You have this issue because you are doing a translateX of -200% so `title` will go out of your box,  you need to hide with `overflow:hidden;` the element `title` that is going out of the box :)

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I'm not too experienced with front-end so I wasn't figure out how to solve this issue.!

Comment: Tried on the codepen example, it will continue to blink if the first title are hovered.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow: hidden;`

```
.card-columns .card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```